# Cypher delete a node and its child node based on condition

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have recently started using Neo4j (version 3.4.1) and still learning the nuances. I have the following the node relationship in my application.
[image]

What I am trying to achieve is the following.

I can delete nodes C1 or C2. I am able to delete their corresponding relationships as well (i.e HAS_X or HAS_Y).

However, when I delete both C1 and C2, node L1 and its other related nodes (M1, M2 and M3) become orphans. Hence, what I want is that whenever I am deleting C1 or C2, if it is the only node that has HAS_Y relationship with node L1, then in that case node L1 and its related nodes (M1, M2 and M3) should also be deleted. If it is not the only node that has HAS_Y relationship with L1, in that case we just delete that specific node (i.e C1/C2). Node L1 and rest of the nodes are left unotuched.
Nodes U1 and U2 remain unaffected in both the scenarios.

I am not sure how I can achieve this using a single cypher query.

**Note :** I was able to achieve my goal by running 2 separate queries (1 for deleting node C1/C2 and another one for deleting orphan node L1). However, it isn't the most performant as I have to make 2 roundtrips to db.

Is anyone able to give me some inputs on how I can achieve this task? I am looking for a cyper query solution (I am avoiding APOC procedures atm as I hear it requires some modification to neo4j db config)

Regards,

V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just Cypher:

```
...// above is your match to 'c', the node to delete
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[:HAS_Y]->(l)
DETACH DELETE c
WITH DISTINCT l
WHERE size(()-[:HAS_Y]->(l)) = 0
OPTIONAL MATCH (l)-[:HAS_Z*0..1]->(toDelete)
DETACH DELETE toDelete
```

We first match to `l`, then we delete `c`. At this point, we only have to take action for any `l` nodes that no longer have any incoming `:HAS_Y` relationships. We filter just for these, and then use an optional match with a 0..1 variable relationship to capture both the `l` nodes and any children they have down `:HAS_Z` relationships, then delete all of those nodes (both `l` and all of its possible children will be addressed via `toDelete`).

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon., your solution works like a charm. It is precisely what I was looking for.